# Setting the PATH so it applies to all users, including root/sudo

Tags: sudo, environment-variables

The instructions in [How do I set PATH variables for all users on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24937/how-do-i-set-path-variables-for-all-users-on-a-server) work to set the PATH for all 'normal' users. However, if I do `sudo -s` and then `printenv PATH` the updated path is not shown. I've taken a look at for example [Setting TeX Live path for root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root), but this does not seem to make sense to me, perhaps as I'm from a Windows background. Is there any way to set the truly system-wide path, such that the entries are inherited by absolutely every process running on the system?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

**Update:**

Setting global environment variables should still be performed in `/etc/environment`, but as you pointed out, using `sudo -s` has the effect of these variables are "vanished".

The reason for that is `sudo` has a policy of *resetting the Environment* and setting a *secure path*. It is enabled by default:

```
/etc/sudoers:

Defaults  env_reset
Defaults  secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Thus whatever is set in the `/etc/environment` for the path is overridden by `sudo`.

The manual page for `sudoers` states:

```
   env_reset       If set, sudo will reset the environment to only contain
                   the LOGNAME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, USERNAME and the SUDO_*
                   variables.  Any variables in the caller's environment
                   that match the env_keep and env_check lists are then
                   added.  The default contents of the env_keep and
                   env_check lists are displayed when sudo is run by root
                   with the -V option.  If the secure_path option is set,
                   its value will be used for the PATH environment
                   variable.  This flag is on by default.
```

As a workaround, you can use `sudo su` that will provide a shell with root privileges but containing the right PATH.

---

**Original Answer**

You should set it in `/etc/environment`.

Try `sudo YOUR_TEXT_EDITOR /etc/environment` (make sure to create a backup first).

For more information: [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

> **System-wide environment variables**
>
> Environment variable settings that affect the system as a whole
>   (rather then just a particular user) should not be placed in any of
>   the many system-level scripts that get executed when the system or the
>   desktop session are loaded, but into
>
> `/etc/environment` - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather
>   consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this
>   file stores the system-wide locale and path settings.
>
> *Not recommended:*
>
> `/etc/profile` - This file gets executed whenever a bash login shell is entered (e.g. when logging in from the console or over ssh), as
>   well as by the DisplayManager when the desktop session loads. This is
>   probably the file you will get referred to when asking veteran UNIX
>   system administrators about environment variables. In Ubuntu, however,
>   this file does little more then invoke the /etc/bash.bashrc file.
>
> `/etc/bash.bashrc` - This is the system-wide version of the ~/.bashrc file. Ubuntu is configured by default to execute this file
>   whenever a user enters a shell or the desktop environment.

Comment: Ah well: to me this is all the wrong way around (everyone should inherit the same path, period), but I guess that's just how it is.

Comment: You can use `visudo` (needs root permissions) to edit the secure path settings. this is not a recommended practice. It is just here for education.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo -i` will simulate a login (in a similar way to `sudo su -`) and thus give you these environment variables.

Comment: It does not work that way. At least PATH gets reset on my Ubuntu Trusty test-vm.

Answer (score 0):

In case we need to add `/usr/local/bin` in `root's PATH` by adding same entry in `/etc/sudoers` file then use sed command as follow

```
sudo sed -i '/^Defaults secure_path/ s/$/\:\/usr\/local\/\bin/' /etc/sudoers
```