# Troubles with permissions of a new user

Tags: permissions, environment-variables, git, adduser

I want to create a new user and give him possibility to use git. So, I've installed git:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

After that I've created a user:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/developer -s /bin/bash -g sudo -m developer
```

And now I have a problem. When I switch to a new user and try to do something like this:

```
git clone <<here is a path>>
```

I get this error message:

```
fatal: unable to access '/home/roman/.config/git/config': Permission denied
```

I can't get why environment variables points to another user folders and what is the good way to fix it. I also believe that I didn't specify something properly during creation of a new user (that is why environment variables have not proper values).

The same problem appears when I try for instance to run mc... I get this:

```
Cannot create /home/roman/.config/mc directory
```

For more information have this

`cat /etc/passwd | grep developer`

```
developer:x:1001:27::/home/developer:/bin/bash
```

So, can somebody explain me how to solve my problems?

Comment: The result of `whoami` is developer. And result of `cat /etc/passwd | grep developer` is `developer:x:1001:27::/home/developer:/bin/bash`.

Comment: Ok, I've changed my question.

Comment: how did you switch to a new user? you should log in as the new user. your problem is likely that you used sudo and the environmental variables were preserved

Comment: How did I switch to another user? kh-kh... `su developer`. And yes I used sudo when ran useradd, because otherwise I will get `useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later`.

Comment: log out and log back in as developer, or use check the man pages for sudo and environmental variables such as $HOME

Answer (score 0):

When you use sudo and/or sudo to switch users, Environmental variables so not necessarily change. It depends on what command you use, options, and configuration.

Example:

```
 sudo -u children echo $HOME
 /home/bodhi
```

Check the man pages for details and/or post your command for help.

[Setting the PATH so it applies to all users, including root/sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128413/setting-the-path-so-it-applies-to-all-users-including-root-sudo)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/su.1.html

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man8/sudo.8.html