# when starting virtualbox vm using sudo, it can't find the VMs

Tags: virtualbox, sudo

I created 2 VMs using VirtualBox and I can start them fine as my own user using the following command:

```
vboxmanage startvm myVM -type headless
```

but when I try the same command with sudo, or in a systemd service, it returns that it can't find the VM.

I found out this

> It fails because you are using sudo. VirtualBox is designed to be run
>   by any user (in the vboxusers group), and sudo runs the command 
>   as the root user whose VirtualBox configuration is empty.

But I just don't know how to make it so when run as root (with sudo) to have virtualbox settings present.

Any idea?

Comment: The end objective here is to auto start the VMs and gracefully terminate them on shutdown.

Comment: Related possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/128413/setting-the-path-so-it-applies-to-all-users-including-root-sudo

Comment: Does the root user have a Virtualbox configuration?

Comment: It's a fresh ubuntu install, so I doubt the root user have a virtualbox configuration. How would I do that?

Comment: The same way you configured it for your user account, but as root. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html might be useful to you. You can clone your existing VM's if so desired.

Comment: Thanks, will read that. I really only apt installed virtualbox and created my VMs from there.. I did not manually add any configuration to my user.

Comment: Beside issuing sudo command, I don't even know how to connect to my root user. su command fail with my password

Comment: `sudo -i` will give you an all powerful root access login. Be careful as it's possible to do a great deal of damage. You should [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) first.

Comment: If your end result should be systemd managing those VMs, have you tried to put your username in the systmed units as executing user? There are also systemd user units, which are run under your user. Maybe this will help you, too. I once did something similar using systemd user mode and vagrant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a VM on login and have it stop on logout, you can use systemd user units.

Create a file `~/.config/systemd/user/myvm.service with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=My VM

[Service]
ExecStart=vboxmanage startvm myVM -type headless
ExecStop=vboxmanage controlvm myVM acpipowerbutton 
# Actually, I'm not sure about the stop command, but I'm confident you will figure that one out
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Afterwards, run `systemctl --user enable myvm.service`. You can now start your VM with `systemctl --user start myvm.service` and stop it with `systemctl --user stop myvm.service`. Logging in and out should start and stop your VM.

If you need this on boot instead of log in, you can try to make this a system systemd unit and specify the executing user in the `[Service]` section with `User=` and `Group=`.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried setting my username in the services' unit, without luck.

Adding the RemainAfterExit saved the day! Thanks a LOT!